# How to have a unique identifier of a Jlabel?

Tags: java, swing

I am new to `java swing` and I am creatin a `Jlabel` as follows :

```
    JLabel Lport = new JLabel ("Port: ");
    final JTextField Tport = new JTextField ("1883", 10);
```

what i want to do is to get the name of the label as a string because i want to use it in a `switch-case`, so i need to get the label name or a unique identifier of that label, some thing like an ID as it exists in Android, i tried the method  ",getAction.toString", ".getName" but none of them displayed the name of the labe, which is according to the code posted is "Port: ". please see my attempts below:

```
if ( (isIPReady(Tip)) && (isPortReady(Tport)) ) {
                    Thread mqttThread = new Thread(MQTTRunnable, MQTT_THREAD);
                    mqttThread.start();
                    System.out.println("Action: " + Tport.get); //here i do not know which method to use
                    setViewEnableState(Bconnect, true);
                }
```

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is to use `JLabel#getText` which will return the text which is displayed by the `JLabel`.

An alternative could be to store your own key-value pair into the different `JComponent` instances. Each `JComponent` allows to [put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) and [retrieve](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getClientProperty-java.lang.Object-) client properties. A copy-paste from the class javadoc:

> Support for component-specific properties. With the
>   putClientProperty(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) and
>   getClientProperty(java.lang.Object) methods, you can associate
>   name-object pairs with any object that descends from JComponent.

This would allow you to write:

```
private static final String ID_KEY = "MyUniqueIDKey";

JLabel label = new JLabel( "Whatever" );
label.putClientProperty( ID_KEY, "labelName" );
```

and then later on

```
String labelName = (String) label.getClientProperty( ID_KEY );
```

Note that this works with any `JComponent`, including `JLabel` and `JTextField` instances like the ones you are using in your code.

Answer (score 1):

JLabel's name is different than the text it displays. To get the text from a JLabel, use getText().

Answer (score 0):

You mention you want the name of the label but in your example you're calling a get on your textfield.

This applies to both a textfield and a label anyway.

That constructor sets the initial text that will display in the text field (or label).

If you want to set a name, you must first set it using setName() then use getName().